# Not able to select item from dropdown menu of bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have created a dropdown using bootstrap but not able to select item from the code is below

```js
var aos = '';
$('.dropdown-item').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevents scrolling to top of page
  aos = $(this).text(); // Get the text value of the thing that was clicked
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">



    <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Project Role
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">PO</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SM</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">AC</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Team Member</a></li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was able to run your code and get the value for aos variable which is text of clicked dropdown item. what you supposed to do after that?

Comment: What do you mean by "select"? Also, your code works just fine for me: try `alert(aos)` -- it shows the item I clicked

Comment: When i try to select item from drop-down it is just showing project role not the item i have selected sorry i edited the code as i forgot to add drop down button

Comment: You are missing the Popper.js library. The browser console shows this: `Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's dropdowns require Popper.js`

Comment: I have added that but issue is still not resole.

Comment: You can run the code and check not able to select from dropdown.

Comment: change the attribute `data-toggle="dropdown"` to `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"`

Comment: Never mind. I thought you were on Bootstrap 5. You are correct having data-toggle="dropdown"` in bs4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use this like a select option

here is the solution.

your function is just need one more line like the following snippet

```js
var aos = '';
$('.dropdown-item').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  aos = $(this).text();
  $('.dropdown-toggle').text(aos); // this is what you have missed.
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">



<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
    Project Role
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">PO</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SM</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">AC</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Team Member</a></li>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just set the option value to the dropdown button.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is working fine

Try to use `console.log` like shown below.

```js
var aos = '';
$('.dropdown-item').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevents scrolling to top of page
  aos = $(this).text(); // Get the text value of the thing that was clicked
  console.log(aos)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">PO</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SM</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">AC</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Team Member</a></li>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: That is not showing a Bootstrap dropdown

Answer (score -1):

try data-bs-toggle="dropdown" to toggle the dropdown

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"` is for Bootstrap 5. The op is using Bootstrap 4 so it is correct with `data-toggle="dropdown"`